# visual studio community 2017 compatibility with windows 7 SP1 professional

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

as above title, having issues to start a project where the studio require to select windows 10. can anyone verify if windows 10 is a must for visual studio 2017 where the official site of Microsoft said otherwise. thanks

Comment: what type of project are you trying to open?

Comment: Yes, Visual Studio 2017 requires Windows 10. You can see at https://www.visualstudio.com

Comment: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/vs2017-compatibility-vs
`Visual Studio 2017 will install and run on the following operating systems: <bla bla>
Windows 7 SP1 (with latest Windows Updates): Home Premium, Professional, Enterprise, Ultimate` I'm running VS2017 without problems on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your project. I am running Visual Studio 2017 Community on Windows 7 and developing in C++, which works fine.

However if you want to develop e.g. an universal windows app, you will be unable to do so. [Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn975273.aspx)

Comment: thanks for the advise. but i just reimage my windows to windwos 10 now. now it works fine.